# Identification of UK insect

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]

We found this in our UK garden! Any ideas? Not sure if it had/has wings.

It has a segmented tail and 6 legs. It’s about 2 inches/ 8cm long.

Comment: It would be helpful to include more information about exactly where in the UK you found this and what kind of habitat.

Comment: That;s the last stage of the dragonfly in the pond, where it eats even tadpoles probably. It climbs out and emerges as a dragonfly, waits for it's wings to dry and flies away.

Comment: If you look at reeds and grass next to ponds at this time of year, you are bond to see many of those.

Answer (score 7):

That looks like the cast off outer layer of a dragon fly nymph§:
[image: Dragon fly larvae from: https://butterfliesandgardens.wordpress.com/tag/dragonfly-larvae/]

The following resources may be helpful to get a more precise identification:

https://www.fba.org.uk/sites/default/files/EA_specid/ea_specid_mod_8.pdf

https://british-dragonflies.org.uk/odonata/species-and-identification/

---

§Note: As pointed out by [Arthur J. Frost](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/32396/arthur-j-frost) this is actually the exoskeleton left behind when a dragonfly nymph molted and became an adult.

Comment: More properly, the OP is _what's left_ of a dragonfly nymph; the adult had emerged and flown off some time prior.

Answer (score 0):

indeed -Exuvieae of a Anisopera dragonfly.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exuviae